# How do I install glosstex in Tex Live?

Tags: packages, texlive

I would like to know how to install the `glosstex` package in TexLive. I don't know where to paste it because I have downloaded it from CTAN. I installed TexLive in Windows 10 Home.

Comment: According to ctan this is software from 1997! Why not use something more modern like the glossaries package and tools

Comment: @daleif I need it for Texis. However, It will be great to know how to install a package in Tex Live that was not listed.

Answer (score 0):

Wowzer that's a challenge it ran out of the box in MSDOS 6.2 circa windows 3.1

Unsure if there may be problems finding a TeX Live from the last century so that it is fully compatible enough to run them together.

The MS-DOS binary supposedly worked on Windows XP (32-bit) - i.e it should say "This is GlossTeX" rather than crashing! It definitely won't work on Windows 64-bit however the old 32-bit versions of Windows had the 16-bit MS-DOS subsystem so it ought to still work on them. If it doesn't work on those then you will have to install a C compiler and rebuild it from its sources roughly as in the PDF instruction manual.

Better alternative might be to find a Linux machine with a suitable make command

Answer (score 0):

After trying to solve my problem, I came up with a solution!

I installed `glosstex` successfully in TeX Live following the next steps:

1. Download from CTAN `glosstex` package.
2. Unzip the file within `texmf-dist/tex/latex folder`
3. Used `cmd` in `texmf-dist/tex/latex` folder and type `latex glosstex.ins`
   This will generate `.sty`, `.std` and `.ist` files.
4. Copy the folder (with the new files) and paste in `texmf-dist/makeindex`

Then it worked out!

Comment: Yes those LaTeX files will potentially work forever but how are you running the binary. Or do you not need that step ?